# Foobar2000 keeps playing the same set of songs even if the order is random

Tags: plugins, music, sorting, foobar2000

I use foobar2000 to listen to music but I kept hearing the same set of songs over and over again.

My playlist has "Still Alive" and "Pure Pwnage" which it always plays even when there is other music in the playlist. I never hear my Tenacious D music even when its in the playlist. It gets rather annoying.

Is there a plugin to change the random number generator or is there a way to get more randomized music for foobar2000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the *Shuffle (tracks)* ordering instead of random.  That should create a random ordering of your playlist and work it's way through it, rather than randomly choosing a new track after the current track finishes.  Note that the shuffled list is recreated when you start Foobar, and probably also when you switch or modify playlists.

Comment: Hey, I just heard a song that I rarely hear on random order. I'm gonna give it another day before accepting this as the answer just in case its a fluke. with random number generators, you can never tell ;)

Comment: I've accepted your answer after 1.5 days of listening. RNGs are hard to test. :D